# Unordered set in c++

Tags: c++, unordered-set

If I provide a custom compare for double, do I have to override the hash? E.g. this piece of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    auto comp = [](double x, double y) { return fabs(x - y) < 1e-10; };
    

    std::unordered_set<double, std::hash<double>, decltype(comp)> theSet(2, std::hash<double>(), comp);

    std::cout.precision(17);
    
    theSet.insert(1.0);
    theSet.insert(1.0 + 1e-13);
    theSet.insert(1.0 - 1e-13);
    theSet.insert(1.2);
    theSet.insert(1.00000000000001);
    theSet.insert(3.2);

    std::cout << "Hash set \n";

    for (const auto& setEl : theSet)
    {
        std::cout << setEl << "\n";
    }   
}
```

Produces (in http://cpp.sh/, when using MS VS Studio 2019 all repeated values seem to remain)

```
Hash set 

1

0.99999999999989997

3.2000000000000002

1.2

1.00000000000001
```

It seems to filter out 1.0 + 1e-13 and 1.0 - 1e-13, but it leaves the other repeated values according to the comparison function.

Comment: Yes you do since values which compare equal must also hash equal. And the bad news is there's no good hash function for your chosen comparator. In fact if you think about it is easy to pick three values a,b, c where a == b and b == c but a != c.

Comment: (continuing the comment above) This makes writing a good hash function difficult, since a and c must have the same hash value even though they are not equal.

Comment: You seem to know that comparing via `==` is not good, but using an epsilon isnt the right thing always either.

Comment: @john: In this case not only difficult but impossible unless all numbers are hashed to to the same value (by transitivity).

Comment: @Peter That's what I originally wrote, but in some places the gap between adjacent numbers is greater than 1e-10. So not every number has to hash equal, just most of them.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I am aware that I am breaking transitivity of equality and that it is an unresolvable problem. But a simple solution similar to the code i wrote above would be sufficient for the problem i have at hand - I have a vector of grid points, which are not too many, say 10 or so at the most, and some of them, but not all may be just the same number coming from a slightly different double representation or computed in a slightly different way. I just need to filter out these "repetitions" and numerically it really won't matter which one of the "equivalent" ones I pick.

Comment: (cont) For example i may have [ 1.0, 1.0+1e-16, 1.0-1e-16, 2.1, 3.2, 3.2+1e-15] and i just need a sub-vector which is  either of the first three, 2.1 and either of the last two. I can use a set with a comparison auto comp = [](double x, double y) { return x + 1e-14 < y; }; for example. It breaks transitivity of equality, but i think it will not matter for what i need it for ... just as a filter. Am I overlooking some pathological case here?

Comment: This turned out to be a much more interesting question than it appeared to be at first sight. +1

Answer (score 0):

You don’t want hashing for this: you want a data structure that **preserves** the relevant order topology, not one that deliberately scrambles the input to be as uniform as possible.  While it is possible to use hashing in conjunction with binning, for your problem a simple **ordered** list or set is sufficient.

If you can **store** all the numbers, you can just sort them and then walk over them skipping ones that are too close (which still admits some ambiguity in terms of which values to compare).  Otherwise, if the number of collisions is high, use a `std::set` and check the **adjacent** values prior to each insertion (again, there is some arbitrariness in that the insertion order affects the result).